# R - Modified mosaic plot from descr package

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data

I have a dataframe `db`with 2 categorical variables: `varA` has 4 levels (`0`,`1`,`2`,`3`), `varB` has 2 levels (`yes`,`no`). `varB` has no values for the level 0 of `varA`:

```
id  varA    varB
1   2       yes
2   3       no
3   3       no
4   1       yes
5   0       NA
6   1       no
7   2       no
8   3       yes
9   3       yes
10  2       no
```

I created a contingency table using `CrossTable` from the `descr` package and then a mosaic plot with the `plot` function:

```
table <- CrossTable(db$varA,db$varB, missing.include=FALSE)
plot(table,xlab="varA",ylab="varB")
```

I obtained this plot:

[image: mosaic plot]

I would like to eliminate the level 0 from the plot. I also would like to add 2 y-axis, one on the left of the plot with a scale from 0 to 1 and one on the right with a scale from 1 to 0.

Could you help me?

Comment: Boy, this sure does look like a question I have seen before. You _should_ post `dput(db)`.

Comment: Still waiting for a reproducible example. I don't think it's my responsibility to create one.

Comment: I added a db example and updated the code and the corresponding plot. Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, *that* was annoying. There is no support for subsetting such a "CrossTable" object. If it were a well-behaved table-like object you would been able to just pass `table[ , -1]` to the plot function. instead you need to do the subetting before the data that is passed to CrossTable:

```
table <- with( na.omit(db), CrossTable( varA, varB, missing.include=TRUE))
plot(table, xlab="varA", ylab="varB")
```

BTW using the name `table` for a data-object is quite confusing to regular R users since the `table` function is one of our basic tools.

Personally I would avoid avoid using that CrossTable function since its output is so weird and not available for management with typical R functions. Yeah, I know it produces a SAS-like output, but R users grow to love the compact output of the `table` function and the many matrix operations that are available for working with table-objects. You may need to get your margin percentages by hand with `prop.table`.

Comment: Thank you DWin. For the same reason I can't add the 2 y-axis?

Comment: I do not understand what that means.